# Selenium using Token to stay login but losing when navigating to different page. Need solution to keep token in local storage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, single-sign-on, access-token

I been working on single sign on solution for smoke test using Selenium and Specflow as the frame work. I am able to get the Access token from local storage and place it back into local storage for the next test to skip the login step but when I navigate to a new page the local storage is wiped and I seen solution where you could add to local store each time you click to new page but this very messy solution.
How I get the token is:

```
string loginToken = ExtractAuthTokenFromResponseBody();
featureContext["auth"] = loginToken;
```

This is how I set local storage. I don't think setting the HeadRequest is correct but currently it does not work with out it. Not sure why

```
//all call the browser
loginPage.Navigate(testConfiguration.URL);

//setting local storage
string nameOfLocalStorage ="Hard coded for know until work more cleanly";
string newTokenValue = featureContext["auth"].ToString();
string script = "var newTokenValue = '" + newTokenValue + "';" + "localStorage.setItem('" + nameOfLocalStorage + "', newTokenValue);";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript(script);

// This adds to head request 
var client = new HttpClient();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(newTokenValue);
string idToken = (string)json["id_token"];
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", idToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(testConfiguration.URL);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(testConfiguration.Url);
```

So when I do GoToUrl it works and I go to main page but when I select new page to navigate to it ends up back at login page due to local storage being empty. I can do some awkward changing of the CLICK function but this for me seem messy. Is there way of keeping local storage through navigation through pages so that I don't need to reset it every time I change page.

To note: the current website I am working on does not use cookies but Token. So this solution would not work.

Sorry for this question being so long but I wanted to give as much context as possible and this is my first time I implementing something like this and so it been a lot experimenting.

Comment: firstly, local storage should not be used for any kind of sensitive information storage.  Cookies are better as they can be set to http-only, secure, same-site, etc...  For your issue, I suppose this site is insecurely reading an authorization token from local storage.  This would need to be done from the same domain.... so is testConfiguration.URL the same domain as testConfiguration.VisualizerUrl?

Comment: I understand it is not safe, and this is not my call. This was done before I joined the company, and I need to work with how things are. Even if it not correct. Yeah, the testConfiguration.URL and testConfiguration.VisualizerUrlare the same. The issue is when I click on the menu option, it is a different URL, which is where the problem is. This is my understanding. So this is what I am trying to solve. 
I hope this make sense.

Comment: Are you sure it's not redirecting you because the custom header is not present?  (or a "remember me" type cookie with the token? token/cookie are not exclusive)  If you execute a script that uses localStorage.getItem('your hardcoded value') after clicking the menu option does the value get returned?  If so, I would check the browser's inspector to check all local storage session storage items.  This value may be expected to be set from a different domain, and the token persisted through the header.

Comment: That a good hint. I will look into that today. It is redirecting me to the login page and never goes to page that click on the menu. there no value return from what I seen so far but I will double check.